# Caring for Aloe Aristata

Tags: identification, plant-care, succulents

Is caring for this plant same as a typical aloe vera?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not aloe-vera however one of its type and comes under category of succulent.

These types of plants need very less water, sun-light and maintenance.

You can check about these types of plant at this [link](https://www.thespruce.com/types-of-aloe-plants-4586709). and [here](https://www.drought-smart-plants.com/aloe-succulent-plants.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what type is this? I couldn't find it on either pages.

Comment: Aloe aristata AKA "Lace Aloe".